# Determining x:1 from the diameter of the Sun and one of its granules.

Tags: ratio, mathematical-astronomy

I'm a having trouble solving the following:  What is the ratio of the diameter of the Sun to the typical width of a granule on the Sun's surface? Express your final answer in the fully factorised form x : 1, where x is a number that you must determine. 
I reduced the numbers but I'm not sure how I'm meant to reduce it to x unless I'm not reducing the ratios correctly? 
A granule on the Sun is about 1000Km across the diameter of the Sun is 1.391016 million km.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use proportion: $$\frac{x}{1}=x=\frac{1.391016 \cdot 10^6}{1000}=1.391016 \cdot 10^3=1391.016$$ You can either round up the result or say that the ratio is $1391016:1000$